# I have a list of characters. I want exact matching for every element of the list using grep in R

Tags: r

I have a list of characters.

```
mylist <- list(c("apple", "banana", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish"), 
              c("apple", "banana", "camel", "doll", "egg"),
              c("apple", "bag", "cat", "donkey", "elephant", "frog", "gun"),
              c("apple", "ball", "cage", "dolphin", "doggy", "fishy"),
              c("apple", "baggy", "catty", "doggy", "eggie", "gun_powder"))
```

I want exact matching of each and every elements of my list with others elements using grep function in R. but what I am getting is partial matching.

This is the code I have written

```
matched <- vector("list", length(mylist))
  for(i in 1:length(mylist))
  {
    index <- NULL
    indexx <- vector("list", length(mylist[[i]]))
    for(j in 1:length(mylist[[i]]))
    {
      dummy <- NULL
      for(k in 1:length(mylist))
      {
        c <- grep(mylist[[i]][j], mylist[[k]], value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
        ind <- c(dummy, c)
        dummy <- ind
      }
      indexx[[j]] <- ind
    }
    matched[[i]] <- indexx
  }
```

Please Help me.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlist your list

```
ulist = unlist(mylist)
```

For each element of `ulist`, find exact matches across all of `ulist`. Do this using equivalence `==` rather than `grep()`, and "vectorize" the comparison.

```
matches0 = lapply(ulist, function(elt) ulist[ulist == elt])
```

Finally, re-list the matches to the original geometry

```
relist(matches0, mylist)
```

It seems strange to summarize the results in this way; perhaps instead count the number of times each word occurs

```
tbl = table(ulist)
```

and use these counts as entries

```
relist(tbl[ulist], mylist)
```

Some tidying is to remove the name of the dimname returned by `table()`,

```
names(dimnames(tbl)) = NULL
```

Comment: I have a large list like this: "Gautam Gambhir_India_KKR", "Robin Uthappa_India_KKR", "Manish Pandey_India_KKR", "John_Hastings_Australia _CSK", "Mahendra Singh Dhoni_India_CSK". I want to replace all countries name and team name(KKR/CSK) to "". May u please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, what you wanted to achieve:

```
    mylist <- list(c("apple", "banana", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish"), 
            c("apple", "banana", "camel", "doll", "egg"),
            c("apple", "bag", "cat", "donkey", "elephant", "frog", "gun"),
            c("apple", "ball", "cage", "dolphin", "doggy", "fishy"),
            c("apple", "baggy", "catty", "doggy", "eggie", "gun_powder"))

    ulist <- unique(unlist(mylist))
    matched <- vector("list", length(ulist))
    names(matched) <- ulist

    ### Counting every fruit
    countList = function(ls, container) { 
        sapply(ls, function(elem) {
                    isEmpty = is.null(container[[elem]])
                    container[[elem]] <<- ifelse(isEmpty, 1, container[[elem]] + 1)
                })
        container
    }
    counted = countList(unlist(mylist), matched)
    lapply(names(counted), function(lab) rep(lab, counted[[lab]]))
```

Output looks like this

```
[[1]]
[1] "apple" "apple" "apple" "apple" "apple"

[[2]]
[1] "banana" "banana"

[[3]]
[1] "cat" "cat"

[[4]]
[1] "dog"

[[5]]
[1] "elephant" "elephant"

[[6]]
[1] "fish"

[[7]]
[1] "camel"

[[8]]
[1] "doll"

[[9]]
[1] "egg"

[[10]]
[1] "bag"

[[11]]
[1] "donkey"

[[12]]
[1] "frog"

[[13]]
[1] "gun"

[[14]]
[1] "ball"

[[15]]
[1] "cage"

[[16]]
[1] "dolphin"

[[17]]
[1] "doggy" "doggy"

[[18]]
[1] "fishy"

[[19]]
[1] "baggy"

[[20]]
[1] "catty"

[[21]]
[1] "eggie"

[[22]]
[1] "gun_powder"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read a tutorial about regular expression [like this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
They are not easy but they are very useful if you work with string. Here there is your code with `regexp`

```
matched <- vector("list", length(mylist))
  for(i in 1:length(mylist))
  {
    index <- NULL
    indexx <- vector("list", length(mylist[[i]]))
    for(j in 1:length(mylist[[i]]))
    {
      dummy <- NULL
      for(k in 1:length(mylist))
      {
        c <- grep(paste("^",mylist[[i]][j],"$",sep=""),mylist[[k]],perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
        ind <- c(dummy, c)
        dummy <- ind
      }
      indexx[[j]] <- ind
    }
    matched[[i]] <- indexx
  }
```

The `^` simbol indicates the start of the string and `$` indicates the end. So it'll get the exact matching.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I got where I was making mistake

Comment: HI, I want to remove some text which is occurring frequently in a list. For example: this is a part of my list "Suresh_Raina_India_CSK", "Mithun Manhas_India_CSK",  "Faf du Plessis_South_Africa_CSK", I want to remove country name and team name(CSK), and want only player name.

Comment: If the string ends always with ... "_country_team" you can use regexp. Use the library "stringr": `library(stringr);
str_replace("Mithun Manhas_India_CSK",perl("_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+$"),"")`

Comment: str_replace("Mithun Manhas_India_CSK",perl("_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+$"),"") is working only if name doesn't contains "_" and country name has only one word. But my list have some names which contain "_" and suffix like New_Zealand_CSK. For example: Brendon_McCullum_New Zealand_CSK

Comment: It's not easy separate the country from the name. You have to understand what could be a pattern that always will be true. The name and surname are always two words ?

Comment: Try with  `str_replace("Brendon_McCullum_New Zealand_CSK",perl("_[a-zA-Z \"]+_[a-zA-Z \"]+$"),"")`